# Lag in my pc because Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued

Tags: windows, hard-drive, lag

I have been facing this issue for more than 1 month.
My specs

- I have an SSD and a HDD in the optical drive port with a caddy.
- Windows 10 64bits
- 8 ram
- Dell laptop

This is the detail in the event log:

[image]

This lag frezze my pc 10 minutes after startup and takes 5-7 min to refresh.

I wanna know 2 things:

1. I wanna know which hard drive it's presenting problems for replace
   it
2. or if the issue have solution,how can i resolve it!

The issue comes after i install nessus which has a service on startup

Comment: Is it still under warranty? Did you ever run the [Dell ePSA](https://www.dell.com/support/article/de-de/sln114988/dell-diagnostic-tools-to-diagnose-and-fix-hardware-problems-on-your-dell-pc-tablet-or-servers?lang=en)?

Comment: Thanks, with your comment i solve the issue, I was missing the driver for amd radeon